# How to manage a huge number of values for a categorical feature in linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new to machine learning and trying to write a linear regression algorithm where I have a categorical feature - Keywords. I can have around 10 million keywords in my model.

As per the instructions given here - http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/multibook/mlt08m.html

It seems like I should dichotomize categorical features. Does it mean I will have 23 feature variables (Dummy coding with 10M levels)?

Is this the best way to handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will essentially have 10 Million predictor variables. This is unavoidable if you are doing regression/classification unless you want to club "similar" keywords together to reduce the number of predictor variables. E.g. you can club keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3 into a single keyword if they share a specific relation among themselves and so on.

To cut down this huge number of keywords (10 M) you have techniques like LASSO (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) and RIDGE (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) penalties. The idea is that most of these 10 M predictor variables are not important in predicting the results and hence you want to remove them early in the learning phase to increase interpretability and avoid overfitting of your results.

Strictly speaking RIDGE is to avoid overfitting and LASSO is to reduce the number of predictors.

Comment: What about feature hashing as a technique?

Comment: 'unless you want to club "similar" keywords together to reduce the number of predictor variables'. 

This similarity can be a hashing technique.

Answer (score 1):

You will get better results if you transform your data to a Sparse Matrix , techniques such as One Hot Encoding and then use any Feature Selection technique(Forward/backward selection,Lasso). Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I handle features such as userId?

Comment: What is your response variable ? Do you think userId will be a good predictor ? If yes, then you will need to convert DataFrame from Long frame to Wide  frame                                                                                                         for eg   Response Variable  UserId29 (0 or 1) UserId30 (0 or 1)  UserId31 i.e convert to a Sparse Matrix.

Comment: Feature hashing would be faster than Sparse Matrix?

Comment: Yeah thats another way.. less memory and requires little pre-processing. I have never used it but model performance usually varies between these 2 methods. If you use it do let me know which method gave better results.